# ng-content not repeating within ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

While placing `<ng-content>` within a `<div *ngFor=...></div>` ,the template comes within the last element of for-loop alone. It does not appear in all the iterated elements.

within my component html ->

```
<ats-tab [tabOptions]="equipmentTabOptions">
    <ng-container class="tab-body">
        <p>para</p> //content to appear in all the tabs
    </ng-container>
</ats-tab>
```

within ats-tab.component.html ->

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div *ngFor="let item of tabOptions;" [attr.id]="item.id" class="tab-pane fade">
      <ng-content select=".tab-body"></ng-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please help! :(

Comment: Not working for me. Got the same issue. Please help!

Comment: can you show us what kind of data you have in tabOptions?

Comment: @ris tabOptions is an array of objects. I will post in a sample below: [
 {
  id: "tab1"
 },
 {
  id: "tab2"
 },
 {
  id: "tab3"
 },
 {
  id: "tab4"
 }
]

Comment: @RomanC, no it is not! The template doesn't come under every instance within the for loop. I even tried using ngForTemplate instead here, but did not work.